# Are HTTP 1.0 directives still relevant?

Tags: http, http-headers, browser-support

I recently spent some time looking for best practices on preventing browsers from caching pages with dynamic content.  In a post here on StackOverflow, someone suggested checking out this page: http://palisade.plynt.com/issues/2008Jul/cache-control-attributes/

The article is from 2008 and mentions the legacy HTTP 1.0 "Pragma" and "Expires" properties.  However, HTTP 1.1 has been around for a while now.  I suppose there is no harm in throwing "Pragma" and "Expires" onto response headers but out of curiosity, is there still a reason to?  Basically, is it safe yet to assume HTTP 1.1 support?  I had some trouble finding info online but it sounds like support has existed in IE since version 4 or 5 and browsers like Firefox don't seem to have HTTP 1.0 options anymore.  Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it's not just browsers you nee to worry about but commonly deployed proxy servers too.

Comment: @Frederick  Good point, although I wonder how many HTTP 1.0 proxies are still around by this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, anything specific to HTTP 1.0 you will not need to work with modern browsers. And most of the web is unusable with the sort of browsers that supported only HTTP 1.0 for many other reasons.

Oh yes, @Frederick brings up a good point. There is [Squid](https://serverfault.com/questions/3828/can-squid-proxy-server-handle-http-1-1-yet-and-for-windows) which has long been HTTP 1.0 only. And there is a lot of that out there.